# Call functions within a method with slightly different inputs

Tags: python

I have a py file with multiple functions inside.

```py
# methods.py
def method_a(input_1, input_2)
...
def method_b(input_1, input_2, input_3)
...
```

I want to call the functions in `methods.py` in my main by the method name as string.

```py
# main.py
import methods

input_1 = ...
input_2 = ...
input_3 = ...

method_name = "method_a"

method = getattr(methods, method_name)

# How to know if I should pass input_3 or not?
output = method(???)
```

So my question is how I can determine if I need to pass `input_3` or not.

So far, I have thought about the following options but I am not sure if they are pythonic...

- Option A: Use `try` statement with the two inputs, if it raises exception, call method with `input_3` added.
- Option B: Use `inspect` and check if `input_3` is an argument of `method`.
- Option C: Update `method_a` to accept `input_3` or `**kwargs` but don't use it, or print a warning. (I don't like this since it raises linting warnings.)

Are they other options to handle this?

Comment: Don't know the final goal and implementation details, but it seems a design flaw. As a workaround you could create a mapping between argument tuples and method (name)s.

Comment: @CristiFati This is part of a higher level code, where users pass a method name as input and see the execution results. I write and control the methods. They have the same functionality but have slightly different inputs.

Comment: Why not option 4: pass as many arguments as you receive from the user and if an exception is thrown, raise the error to the user. Of course, you can catch it and print a nicer message than a stack trace. If the user gets to pick which function to use, it's the user's responsibility to pass the correct number of arguments.

Comment: Put the inputs in a list, then you can use `method(*input_list)`